# Synchronization issue in Python

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading

I am trying to understand synchronization and have the following code with Reentrant lock

```
import threading
from time import sleep,ctime,time

class show:

    lock=threading.RLock()

    def __init__(self):
        self.x=0

    def increment(self):
        show.lock.acquire()
        print("x=",self.x)
    #   show.lock.acquire()
        self.x+=1
        show.lock.release()



class mythread(threading.Thread):
        def __init__(self,aa):
            super().__init__(group=None)
            self.obj=aa
        def run(self):
            for i in range(0,100):
                self.obj.increment()
ss=show()
ss1=show()
one=mythread(ss)
two=mythread(ss)
one.start()
two.start()
```

Now if i run the code as above things are working fine and i get output from 0 to 199. But if i uncomment the line above where we reacquire the lock the output is 0 to 99. why is this change. how reacquiring lock is changing the output

Answer (score 1):

After uncommenting, one of threads is blocked by another which still holds a hundered of locks on class `show` after terminating. You should always match number of aquired and releases locks even if using recursive (aka reentrant) locks.

Check the Wikipedia or the docs for the rlock definition. The latter says:

> To unlock the lock, a thread calls its release() method.
>   acquire()/release() **call pairs** may be nested; only the final release()
>   (the release() of the outermost pair) resets the lock to unlocked and
>   allows another thread blocked in acquire() to proceed.

To avoid the issues with missing lock releases I recommend a context manager

```
def increment(self):
    with show.lock:      
        print("x=", self.x)       
        self.x += 1
```

Comment: The output is fine till we re-acquire the lock. This is what is not clear

Comment: The point of lock(s) to block execution of other threads. If one of theads gets 100 unreleased locks, the other cannot execute because they lock on the same object (show)

Comment: yes i think i should release twice is where i am wrong. is it

Comment: yup. or better acquire just once